# remote weblogic server identity exception

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

When I try to start a weblogic server (which runs on another server) from my local machine I am getting below error. I can stop this weblogic server without any problem but I couldn't start. There are username and password fields in boot.properties file but I don't know what are they. Is there any idea?

```
<Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. 
Reason: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: 
Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid; 
The user name and/or password from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.
weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid; The user name and/or password from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.
at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:960)
at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1054)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:148)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 7):

just delete file which is ManagedServerDir/data/ldap & restart domain yourdomain/bin ./startWeblogic.sh

Answer (score 4):

You can save username and password in your boot.properties file.

In production mode, the boot.properties file doesn’t exist. Need to create this file in

```
$DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/security
```

I think you need check this path and this properties. May be the password or username is incorrect.

[Here is link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/15-BootProp--4471/bootproperties.htm?cid=6175&ssid=102232643811781) which show how to create and find this propreties.

If it doesn't find or can't rewrite it, you can start the server without the boot.properties file:

```
java -Dweblogic.management.username=username-Dweblogic.management.password=password -Dweblogic.system.StoreBootIdentity=true -Dweblogic.Name=myAdminServer weblogic.Server
```

This script, I find in [this page.](http://tim.blackamber.org.uk/?p=863)

---

**Edit:**

Now I found some usefull tips in [another](http://www.weblogic-tips.com/2010/05/12/20100512how-to-resolve-authentication-denied-boot-identity-not-valid/) [forum](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2385131).

1. edit the boot.properties file, use plain text username and password instead of encrypted like:

   > Username: weblogic 
   > password: Weblogic1

   After start the server from command line, it will encrypt again automitically.
2. remove the ManagedServerDir/data/ldap directory completely.
3. **Always keep backup of files before removing it**.
4. Now try to start the server from the command prompt and provide the username/password used to login to the Admin Console.

And found this tip from [weblogictips user of same forum](http://www.weblogic-tips.com/2010/05/12/20100512how-to-resolve-authentication-denied-boot-identity-not-valid/#comment-876):

I think before try these tips that you should check your the authentication provider for the domain. If it is external then you may need to reset the password from external ldap.

> Also move the ldap dir and boot.properties files if locally present.
>
> Only difference in case the server is started through the Admin
>   Console / WLST is that you have to move the nodemanager dir also
>   present is the doamin_home/servers/ms1/data/nodemanager

---

I hope these tips are help to you. If not please try delete username and password (don't necessary to delete `username=` in file) in all boot.properties file and start from beginning...

Comment: I have boot.properties file and I saved my username and pass but error still continues. The thing is I can start this weblogic server locally but I couldn't start it remotely. Do I need to do something extra?

Comment: Are you have simple admin server or more severs? Can you check node managers boot.properties? You can find at `DOMAIN_HOME/servers/server_name/data/nodemanager`.

Comment: But if you could start weblogic locally, than it is not a wrong username/passworld problem. How do you start weblogic locally and how remote?

Comment: I have 2 server instansce on remote machine "AdminServer" and "myServer". I also have 2 servers on my local machine called "AdminServer" and "myServer"(this server points to remote "myServer"). I can start "myServer" on remote machine from admin console without any problem but when I try to run "myServer" from my local machine again with admin console it gives this error.

Comment: By the way I can't start remote "myServer" from my local machine but I can stop it without any problem :D

Comment: When you installed weblogic which [mode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e14140/configuration_screens.htm#WLDCW209) are you selected?

Comment: I don't remember which one but Default one :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43134/discussion-between-herry-and-hellzone)

Comment: I edited my answer. Add another tips. Please try it! I hope it help to you!

Comment: I deleted ldap directory and changed username and password to plain text. After I start server remotely It creates ldap directory again and encryptes username and password but error still continues. I have found that there are many people dealing with this error and many of them couldn't solved. There are hundreds of topics at Oracle forums about this error and none of them solved. I think either this error is a bug or weblogic server doesn't support cluster completely.

Answer (score 1):

i got this error when I accidentally changed the username and password in boot.properties and it took me a while to figure out the cause.
it has the encrypted user name and password which is for the security purpose and to reset it I had to remove the encrypted user name and password and enter the correct one in the same pattern which that file expects. But still weblogic startup was failing and the reason was the due to LDAP connection which it was making with the wrong credentials which i entered before so i deleted the 'data' folder from the servers folder along with tmp, cache and security. It worked as the ldap was created with the new weblogic credentials.

Keep backup when u are doing any changes in the servers directory to revert back in case if the workaround is not helping.